# Use Clang instead of GCC with Android studio 2.2's CMake support

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake

We're trying to make use of the new CMake support in Android Studio's 2.2 gradle.

By default, the toolchain is set to use GCC and it seems to be broken, so compilation fails miserably.

How can I tell it to work with clang?

I tried to use `-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.5` in the Arguments parameter within the scope of CMake in our build.gradle, but that also fails (it was documented in the comments of android.toolchain.cmake that came with the NDK claiming that such toolchain doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google seem to have updated their documentation on that, adding a new -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang argument, see -

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/external-c-builds

*UPDATE*
Latest Android Studio builds as of today (Aug 21, 2016) have a checkbox when starting a new project, to enable C++ Support, I tested it on Windows and it works.

Cheers